# Word order in a sentence with "What do you think..." in the beginning

Tags: grammar, word-order

Which of the following two sentences is correct?

1. What do you think are your weak spots?
2. What do you think your weak spots are?

Comment: Hello, Malevych. Do you think either is incorrect, and if so, in what way? Unless the poster mentions (pinpoints) a concern, questions reading 'Is this question / paragraph correct?' are proofreading, not focused enough for ELU. Here, for instance, are you concerned about missing punctuation? Using 'what'? ...

Comment: You may not be aware of our sister site SE English Language Learners, which caters for questions of this type, from those learning English.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> [1] *What do you think* [*___ are your weak spots*]*?*
>
> [2] *What do you think* [*your weak spots are ___*]*?*

It's a free choice between the two. They both entail the same meaning and they are both grammatical.

They are essentially two different ways of asking the same thing, though the grammar is slightly different in that "what" has a different function in [1] and [2].

In [1] "what" is the subject of the bracketed embedded clause functioning as complement of "think".

In [2] "what" is predicative complement of "are" in the embedded clause.

Answer (score 2):

- *What are your weak spots?*

is obviously correct.

1. *What do you think are your weak spots?*

is arguably the matrix sentence with the parenthetical 'do you think', almost a speech tag (cf *said Jan*), inserted. Some might prefer offsetting commas, but the sentence is grammatical.

2. *What do you think your weak spots are?*

is comparable to 'I think [that] my weak spots are ...', and is again grammatical.

The second variant here is the less formal (but not informal).